# Coincidence??? 7000 in 1 Kings 19:18 ... 7000 in Revelation 11:13

Tags: revelation

> [1Ki 19:18 NASB95] [18] "Yet I will leave 7,000 in Israel, all the knees that have not bowed to Baal and every mouth that has not kissed him."

> [Rev 11:13 NASB95] [13] And in that hour there was a great earthquake, and a tenth of the city fell; seven thousand people were killed in the earthquake, and the rest were terrified and gave glory to the God of heaven.

Any revelations, does anyone else not find it interesting? Any comments or thoughts appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This is no coincidence - the repetition of the number 7000 in Rev 11;13 is direct allusion to the 7000 in 1 Kings 19:18 as the miraculous remnant of those preserved by God.  see appendix below for a longer discussion of this point.

Thus, 7000 people is associated with a "remnant":

> And in that hour there was a great earthquake, and a tenth of the city
> collapsed. 7000 were killed in the quake, and the rest [λοιπός =
> remnant] were terrified and gave glory to the God of heaven.

However, there is an important set of DIFFERENCES between these two groups of 7000.

- In 1 Kings 19:18 the 7000 are preserved as righteous; Rev 11:13 - the 7000 righteous martyrs die

In the book of Revelation, the word translated "remnant" occurs eight times as follows:

- Rev 2:24 - the remnant who do not hold to Jezebel's teaching and have not learned Satan’s so-called deep secrets
- Rev 3:2 - Church is Sardis told to strengthen those who remain = the righteousness remnant
- Rev 8:13 - the remaining trumpet blasts
- Rev 9:20 - the remnant of mankind not killed by plagues - this is a wicked remnant because they continue to worship idols and demons
- Rev 11:13 - the remnant of those not among the 7000 dead killed by the earthquake
- Rev 12:17 - the righteous remnant who keep the commandments of God and hold to the testimony of Jesus
- Rev 19:21 - the wicked remnant who were killed with the sword coming out of the mouth of the rider on the horse
- Rev 20:5 - the dead wicked remnant who did not come back to life until the thousand years were complete

**APPENDIX - Remnant**

As used in the Bible, the “Remnant” consists of the few people left over after a catastrophe that are miraculously saved by God.  The idea is quite common in the Old Testament and is referenced a number of times in the New Testament.  The table below shows this idea more clearly.

| References | Catastrophe | Remnant | Divine Miracle |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gen 7:1, 23 | Flood | Noah and family | Preserved in the ark |
| Gen 19 | Sodom and Gomorrah destroyed | Lot and 2 daughters | Saved by angels |
| Gen 45:7, 50:20 | Famine in Palestine | Jacob’s family | Preserved by Joseph |
| 1 Kings 19:18 | Baal apostasy in Israel and drought | 7000 who have not kissed Baal | God’s faithful preserved |
| 2 Kings 17:8, 19:4, 6, 30, 31, 2 Chron 15:9, Isa 10:20-22, 11:16 | Assyria’s captivity of Israel | Judah | Hezekiah’s deliverance from Sennacherib |
| 2 Chron 34:21, 36:20, Ezra 1:4, 2:1, 2, 9:8, 13-15, Neh 1:2, 3, Isa 1:9, 10:20-22 | Babylon’s destruction of Jerusalem | A few of the royal line and nobility | Preserved until return from Babylon |
| Acts 15:17, Rom 9:27, 29, 11:5, Joel 2:32 | Transition to Christian community | Christian community | Pentecost, etc. |
| Rev 12:17 (see also Rev 2:24) | Persecution by the Dragon | Those that keep the commandments of God and have the Testimony of Jesus | God’s faithful preserved |

Comment: Excellent presentation. Up-voted +1.

Comment: I have difficulty to understand why these 7000 deaths in Revelation 11:13 were remnant

Comment: @VincentWong - the 7000 in 1 Kings 19:18 are called a remnant explicitly.  Those that were left.

Comment: @Dottard - I agree the 7000 in 1 Kings 19:18 were remnant, but the 7000 deaths in Revelation 11:13 were not, for they were not left ALIVE. In your table, all the remnant were alive and how was these 7000 deaths in Revelation an allusion to 1 Kings by simply connected by the number 7000?

Comment: @VincentWong - look at Rev 20:5 where the Greel "loipos" (remainer/remnant/rest) is applied directly to "the dead".

Comment: @Dottard - Thank you for your reply. However, the rest in here represent those who wait for their resurrection after the millennium. It does not apply just to these 7000. Moreover, these 'the rest' includes those whose names in the book of life, as well as those who were not.

Answer (score 2):

#### Are the 7,000 (1 Kgs. 19:18) and the 7,000 (Rev. 11:13) coincidental?

Answer: **I believe they are simply that** as I explain below.

This is how I feel the text might be properly interpreted based on my own studies:

| Point # | Explanation | Rev. Verse |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | Reference to "the nations" is characterizing the Gentiles | 11:2 |
| 2. | These are the Romans and other nations beyond Israel | 11:2 |
| 3. | The Romans would tread Jerusalem underfoot for forty-two months | 11:2 |
| 4. | This would be known as the 3<sup>1/2</sup> year "Siege of Jerusalem" in AD 70 | 11:2 |
| 5. | God's two witnesses were Moses and Elijah — representative of the O/T Law | 11:3 |
| 6. | The Law would survive the twelve hundred sixty day (42 months, or 3<sup>1/2</sup> year) siege to come | 11:3 |
| 7. | The Law would metaphorically be "looking upon" Israel's evil (metaphorically clothed in sackcloth) | 11:3 |
| 8. | The two olive trees and the two lampstands before the Lord represent Moses and Elijah — as described in Zech. 4:2-6 | 11:4 |
| 9. | Moses and Elijah are the Lord's two anointed, where | 11:4 |
| 10. | *Christ is the golden lampstand*, the Menorah in the midst of them (Zech. 4:2). Perhaps we are meant to recognize this from the Mount of Transfiguration, where Christ stood among Moses and Elijah in glory? | 11:4 |
| 11. | The Word of God is a consuming fire | 11:5 |
| 12. | Anyone who wishes them harm is rejecting the Sacred Word, and is consumed by fire (Hell) | 11:5 |
| 13. | Fire flows out of their mouth to devour their enemies in the flames of Hades | 11:5 |
| 14. | The first witness, Elijah, has the power to shut up the sky preventing rain while prophesying | 11:6 |
| 15. | The second witness, Moses, has the power to turn the waters to blood | 11:6 |
| 16. | Striking the earth with every plague was also the prerogative of Moses | 11:6 |
| 17. | When finished with their testimony: the Word of God, the beast from the abyss, the Devil, works through the ungodly | 11:7 |
| 18. | They overcome (reject) the Law, thus "killing it" | 11:7 |
| 19. | Leaving metaphorical dead bodies in the street is extreme disrespect to God | 11:8 |
| 20. | The great city mystically called Sodom and Egypt metaphorically describes Jerusalem, and, | 11:8 |
| 21. | We can know this because it was where our Lord was crucified | 11:8 |
| 22. | Peoples and tribes and tongues and nations, the Gentiles, will marvel over the wickedness of Israel, knowing that their God has commanded against it | 11:9 |
| 23. | Not permitting dead bodies to be buried is a profound level of contempt by Israel | 11:9 |
| 24. | In this context, "those who dwell on the earth rejoicing over carcasses" appears to be Israel, now believing it had gotten away with its evils | 11:10 |
| 25. | Sending gifts to one another is rejoicing over their lawless deeds | 11:10 |
| 26. | Moses and Elijah (the O/T) had tormented the ungodly by convicting them | 11:10 |
| 27. | The "breath of life from God into the witnesses" was God's holding the transgressors accountable | 11:11 |
| 28. | The licentiousness of Israel was about to be punished, because, | 11:11 |
| 29. | Great fear came upon many who had participated in such evil | 11:11 |
| 30. | God will now strike with another woe, as Israel was thoroughly convicted of their own guilt | 11:12 |
| 31. | The great earthquake was part of the second woe, where there were massive casualties | 11:13 |

**Here, let us contrast the text of 1 Kgs. 19:18 with that of Rev. 11:13**:

> **1 Kings 19:18**: “Yet *I will leave 7,000 in Israel, all the knees that have not bowed to Baal* and every mouth that has not kissed him.”
> **Revelation 11:13**: "[There] was a great earthquake, and a tenth of the city fell; **seven thousand people were killed in the earthquake**"

**It seems unclear that the 7,000 were martyrs**. Merely dying from a catastrophic event doesn't necessarily equate to "martyrdom." Note that in the first case, God is sparing the 7,000 of 1 Kgs 19, whereas here in Rev. 11, they are being destroyed.

That is especially true as we consider that *Christians* escaped to the mountains of Pella, Jordan for safety and were spared. Any 7,000 people remaining in Judah *against the warnings of Christ* would probably never have heeded anything else He had to say, and were lost in their sins along with the rest of Judah.

To continue then:

| Point # | Explanation | Rev. Verse |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 32. | It seems seven thousand merely died in an ensuing earthquake | 11:13 |
| 33. | Finally, well after the fact, *some in Israel* (we don't know who) tried to gave glory to God but were to late. If they had *at all* become faithful to Christ, their conversion was a day late and a dollar short. | 11:13 |

**The symbolism in Revelation 11 is intriguing. However, any similarities between 1 Kgs. 19:18 and Rev. 11:13 appear to be coincidental**.

Comment: Very unconvincing compared to @Dottard.

Comment: @NigelJ Thanks for the comment. We know that the faithful of God, understanding Christ's words - and *trusting them*, fled to the mountains of Jordan. Perhaps you can tell me precisely how the 7,000 in Revelation 11 speak to the 7,000 in 1 Kgs. 19? Where do we learn that the 7,000 in Revelation were *ever* martyrs whatsoever? How is merely being killed by an earthquake synonymous with "martyrdom"?

Answer (score 0):

The nearest reference to the 7000 of 1Ki.19:18 is 1 Kings 20:15 "Then he [Ahab] mustered the young men of the rulers of the provinces, and there were 232; and after them he mustered all the people, even all the sons of Israel, seven thousand".

Nevertheless, it was interesting to see the 7000 in Rev.11:13. If you want to make a case for this 7000 among the faithful, you could reason that: 1) They were in the vicinity of the Two Witnesses' ministry, therefore they might be the people who were impacted by their ministry the most. 2) In the same way that "great fear" (megas phobos" fell by those who saw the resurrection/ascension of the Two Witnesses, the people who saw the 7000 killed were "terrified" (emphoboi) and even gave glory to God of heaven. I would admit that this line of reasoning is much weaker than it should be, therefore I think that this 7000 is NOT a remnant in the sense of 1Ki.19:18 you mentioned.

Comment: Welcome to Bible Hermeneutics and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803).